# Talend MySQL flow keeps stopping at 11599 rows

Tags: mysql, talend, data-integration

I have created a job in Talend Open Studio for Data Integration. It runs and does the right thing but keeps stopping at 11599 rows when I run it. The only advanced setting I have used is Enable Stream to ease memory usage.

[image: d]

Comment: Hello, can you post the error message that you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. It just stops loading but looks like the debug is still running. The table stops growing when I check a COUNT(*) o fthe table

Comment: Why would you add a commit with a main row? Please try replacing row2 with OnComponentOk trigger

Comment: I used the commit because no rows were saving to the destination DB. If I remove that then nothing happens. And it still stops at 11599 rows. What must I do with the OnComponentOK tigger? The dw fact table is the end of the line

Comment: When you open a DB connection, you can enable AutoCommit from the Advanced Option. This way you can remove the Commit component and it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah I did that but It's still blocking me at 11599 rows for some reason? Could it be a MySQL Server config issue?

Comment: It's weird but possible. I recommend using a bulk insert component like tDBBulkExec and see if that works. It is also faster.

Comment: So all of these recommendation are cool. Thanks. BUT, it seems the problem is coming from the tDBInput itself. No matter what I do it always freezes at 11599 rows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ah so it turns out there was something wrong with the row 11600 (hence why it went to 11599 and then stopped). Still trying to figure out what though.

Comment: Execute the job without debug mode you will get an error

Comment: You cannot as questions in Answers post. Please remove and edit in questions layout

Answer (score 1):

When you use Commit component, it will fetch all the records from the source and commits all together. 11599 entries are getting committed in one shot which reduces the performance of the job. Instead avoid using commit component and use advanced settings in output component and provide the commit interval. Eg: if you provide commit interval of 1000, it commits every 1000 records together in the target.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But like I said above the problem comes from the tMysqlInput that just stops at 11599 always. So strange...

Comment: Its actually not getting stopped, it is committing the records in your database in the background. Data gets committed according to the latency you have. Please use commit interval in the output component which will resolve your issue

Comment: I tried that and it did the same thing. It committed up to 11000 (at 1000 intervals) and then stopped at the tbinput at 11599. Even if I output to a file it stops there. And it's not the query. Because if I run it in MySQL Workbench it returns more than that.

Comment: You are running the job in your local machine or from any other server?

Comment: On my machine in debug mode

Comment: Do not execute in debug mode